# DB query is returning undefined value in node.js with oracledb

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, protractor

i am new to node.js and javascript and trying to learn the things. in my tests i need to pick a value from Oracle DB through select query and need to use it in to my code later. i am referring the same code given on https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/introducing_node_oracledb_a_node and it is working fine but am not able to return the result value.

below is my code :

```
this.getTableData = function(){
        var res;
        oracledb.getConnection(
                {
                    user : "user",
                    password      : "password",
                    connectString : "db " 
                },
                function (err, connection) {
                    if (err) { 
                                console.error(err);
                                console.log("errorrrrrrrrrrr : "+err);
                                return;
                                }               
                    connection.execute("SELECT query",
                         function(err, result) { 
                                    if (err) { 
                                        console.error(err); 
                                            return; 
                                        }
                                    else if(result) {
                                        res = result.rows[0][0];
                                        console.log("result in else if: "+res);
                                        return res;
                                    }});
                    });
    };
```

the function returns undefined value.

Comment: What's the actual query? What's the value of `result`, as opposed to `result.rows[0][0]`? What's the value of `result.rows`?

Comment: The query is "SELECT OTPCODE FROM (SELECT OTPCODE FROM ONETIMEPASSWORD WHERE MSISDN = 91123456789 Order BY GENERATED_ON DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1" and the result.rows & result.rows[0][0] returns as six digit value from table like 123456

Answer (score 8):

Of course it returns `undefined`. It's because of async callback functions. You'll need to do something like this:

```
this.getTableData = function(callback){
    oracledb.getConnection(
        {
            user : "user",
            password      : "password",
            connectString : "db "
        },
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                console.log("errorrrrrrrrrrr : "+err);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute("SELECT query",
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(result) {
                        var res = result.rows[0][0];
                        console.log("result in else if: "+res);
                        callback(res);
                    }});
        });
};

getTableData(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The other way you could solve this problem is using a `Promise`:

```
this.getTableData = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        oracledb.getConnection(
            {
                user: "user",
                password: "password",
                connectString: "db "
            },
            function (err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                    console.log("errorrrrrrrrrrr : " + err);
                    return;
                }
                connection.execute("SELECT query",
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            reject(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (result) {
                            var res = result.rows[0][0];
                            console.log("result in else if: " + res);
                            resolve(res);
                        }
                    });
            });
    });

};

getTableData()
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The code you've asked for in your comment:

```
var AddPage = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.enterOtpInput = element(by.model("beneDetail.otp"));
    this.enterMpinInput = element(by.model("retailerMpin"));
    this.verifyBeneficiaryButton = element(by.xpath("//div[2]/div/button"));
    this.verifyBene = function () {
        support.getTableData()
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log("adam: " + result);
                self.enterOtpInput.sendKeys(result);
                self.enterMpinInput.sendKeys("1111");
                self.verifyBeneficiaryButton.click();
            });

    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) the above code is working. but i have one more requirement as i need to input the value of result into a textfield on webpage as : this.element(by.model("otp")).sendKeys(result);

Comment: is their any way i can set value of result to some global variable and use that into sendKeys() as parameter value. I m using Protractor + Jasmine framework. Thanks for Help in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i have tried in this way but it is not working. the statement self.element(by.model("otp")).sendKeys(result); is not getting executing.

Comment: I could only help if I saw where you're trying to call the function.

Comment: the code is a complete JS file ; var AddPage = function() {
 
 this.enterOtpInput = element(by.model("beneDetail.otp"));
 this.enterMpinInput = element(by.model("retailerMpin"));
 this.verifyBeneficiaryButton = element(by.xpath("//div[2]/div/button"));

 
 
 this.verifyBene = function() {
      
  support.getTableData().then(function (result) {
         console.log("adam: "+result);
         this.enterOtpInput.sendKeys(result);
     });
        this.enterMpinInput.sendKeys("1111");
        this.verifyBeneficiaryButton.click();
        };

Comment: i have a nother Support.js class in which i have created the main getTableData() function.

Comment: I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but why are we using self variable? Actually the flow of my test is like this 1. Login 2. search something on home page 3. Search navigates to next page 4. Click on add button 5. New page opens up and Enter few details 6. Click on Confirm and read result value from DB 7. Enter result value into Input field.       The method shared above named AddBene() actually performs point 7. when i tried with the code given above by you, it starts looking for enterOtpInput value only after step 4. This results into error as that particular field is not displaying on UI yet.

Comment: Read this: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/ and this: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. i am going through these now. but for now can you please help me in resolving this issue :)

Comment: I've modified the code a bit. Still not working? if not, pls explain what is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for showing the Promise example it works!